# Создание дискорд бота для спама

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

```
import discord
import time

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Connected to Discord! {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.lower() == '"spam':
        while True:
            await message.channel.send('SPAM')
            time.sleep(2)
            if message.content.lower() == '"stop':
                break


client.run('token')
```

Короче, хотел для тренировки создать бот для дискорда, который как только кто нибудь вводит сообщение "spam в чат дискорд-сервера, бот начинал спамить одно сообщение "SPAM, а как только кто нибудь вводил "stop то он бы останавливался, но у меня не получилось и он не останавливается, а продолжает спамить! Как решить данную проблему (мне нужен не только совет как это исправить, но и исправленный код, пожалуйста)
Код вверху

Answer (score 0):

В асинхроне не силен но суть думаю плюс минус одна.

У тебя обработчик сообщений получил слово `спам` и ушёл в бесконечный цикл отправки.. и пока он в бесконечном цикле он не получит заветное слово `стоп`.

Попробуй так

```
    spam = False #Создаем переменную спам, и устанавливаем значение фолс
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        if message.content.lower() == '"spam':
            spam = True #Задаём true
            while spam: #Если spam true то спамим, а если false то перестаём.
                await message.channel.send('SPAM')
                time.sleep(2)

        if message.content.lower() == '"stop':
            spam = False #Получили смс стоп, задали фолс для остановки спама
```

Comment: Не, тоже не работает

Comment: Посмотри меняется ли вообще значение переменной спам или нет

Comment: spam должен быть в таком случае глобал переменной, и вместо time.sleep использовать await asyncio.sleep